# Where is an example of a feature test testing bitcoin-cli?

Tags: bitcoin-core-development, functional-test

Looking for an example so I can run some functional tests against bitcoin-cli.

Answer (score 4):

[test/functional/interface_bitcoin_cli.py](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/0ebd4db32b39cb7c505148f090df4b7ac778c307/test/functional/interface_bitcoin_cli.py) is a test for bitcoin-cli itself.

Comment: how did I miss that? Lol ty.